# VueJs only show google map when location is set

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, google-maps-markers, vue.js

So I'm trying to build a simple app that shows distance to locations on a Google map, from a user's current location.

I'm using `Vue.js 1.0` and the `vue-google-maps` plugin.

I'm trying to center the Google map on user's location, but can only get the map to load if I hard code the longitude and latitude data in my application like this:

```
 export default {

        data: function data() {

            return {
                center:{ lat:28.2328382, lng: -3.298973987232 },
                mapBounds: {},
                usermarkers:  [],
                businessmarkers: [],
                zoomControl: true,
                mapTypeControl: true,
                data: {
                    currentLocation: '',
                    search: {
                        lon: '',
                        lat: '',
                        unit: '',
                        order: 'asc',
                        distance: '',
                        type: ''
                    }
                },
            };
        },
```

My map is rendered here:

```
    <map :center.sync="center" :zoom.sync="zoom" :map-type-id.sync="mapType" :options="{styles: mapStyles}">
                <marker v-for="m in usermarkers" :position.sync="m.position">
                    <info-window :position="center" :content="ifw2text"></info-window>
                </marker>
                <marker v-for="m in businessmarkers" :position.sync="m.position">
                    <info-window :position="center" :content="m.ifw2text"></info-window>
                </marker>
            </map>
```

Then in the ready function I grab the geolocation of the user via html5 and push the user's marker on to the map.

So what I'm now trying to do is dynamically center the location.

I wrapped my map html in a conditional statement like so

```
      <div v-if="!data.center.lat && !data.center.lng">
            <map :center.sync="center" :zoom.sync="zoom" :map-type-id.sync="mapType" :options="{styles: mapStyles}">
                <marker v-for="m in usermarkers" :position.sync="m.position">
                    <info-window :position="center" :content="ifw2text"></info-window>
                </marker>
                <marker v-for="m in businessmarkers" :position.sync="m.position">
                    <info-window :position="center" :content="m.ifw2text"></info-window>
                </marker>
            </map>
        </div>
```

in my data function I leave the center empty

```
data: function data() {

            return {
                center:'',
```

Then my ready function grabs the geolocation builds the center object and sets this.center correctly

```
   ready () {

        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

            let centerObj ={};

            centerObj.lat = position.coords.latitude;
            centerObj.lng = position.coords.longitude;

            this.center = centerObj;

            this.usermarkers.push({
                position: { lat:this.center.lat, lng: this.center.lng }
             });

            }.bind(this), function (error) {
                if (error.code == error.PERMISSION_DENIED)
                    alert('Please Enable Location Services');
            }.bind(this));
        }

    },
```

My console.log show the center.lat and center.lng are set but the map is still not being rendered. Shouldn't vue reload the virtual DOM when data like this is set, thus rendering the map? Am I missing something really simple or going about this the complete wrong way?

Comment: No one knows this?